# combine two functions into a UITableViewCell: selection and information

Tags: iphone

I'm using a UITableView to present options to the user. The user can select one option by clicking on one of the cells. The concept is similar to the Radio input in html forms.

I'm looking for some ideas on how to combine two functions into a UITableViewCell.
I've taken care of the selection function. I would like to also let the user get information on a particular UITableViewCell.
The information is text that will not fit into a subtitle on the UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Create mirror arrays, one with info for the selection, and one with the other information; then on selection, insert the other info into the first array in the appropriate position and display

Or

Create a footer under the tableView and display the info whenever a cell is selected.

Comment: thanks! I decided to go with a UIView that slides up half way